# Vue choosing theme at build time

Tags: vue.js

I have an application, which gets deployed with two themes -- "normal" and accessibility -- which are implemented by having rules

```
#app.default {
    @import './assets/scss/app.scss';
    font-family: $font-family-base;
}

#app.accessibility {
    @import './assets/scss/app-accessibility.scss';
}
```

and binding #app's style attribute. I have a need to deploy this same application in multiple places, but with a different "normal" theme. What are the strategies to be able to choose which theme to use during build time, while preserving ability to switch to (always same) accessibility theme at runtime? This compilation is done from an ant script, so I could in principle use eg app1.scss and app2.scss files for different deployments, and then before invoking vue build, copy chosen file to app.scss. This doesn't look like a clean solution to me though, are there better options?

Comment: You can add an HTML attribute which contains the domain where the app is actually deployed, e.g. `<div id="app" :deploy="window.location.hostname">` and then add relevant CSS selectors, e.g. `#app.default[deploy="app.test.example.com"]`

Comment: I don't want to include themes that aren't being used in the bundle

Comment: Well, then your best bet is to use CSS variables (also called custom properties) - then you can deploy different CSS file with the appropriate CSS variables for each deployment, while the source code will stay the same and will be built only once.